# UI alert tableview not working in ios7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uialertview

I have problem in uialerttable view in ios7 .I have used the same code its working in ios6 but it's not supported in ios7 .It won't go for cell for row index path for table view. This the link https://github.com/blommegard/SBTableAlert , I have downloaded it work fine ios 6 but ios 7 have a problem please help me out friends. Thanks advance.

Answer (score 2):

iOS does not support adding `subview` to `UIAlertView` after **iOS 7**. So the library you using will not work in iOS7 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

If you have any problem with github code, just look at the issue list in Github code page. I founded that a solution which was mentioned in that page. Look at this [link](https://github.com/blommegard/SBTableAlert/pull/24). They Replaced `UIAlertView` with [TSAlertView](https://github.com/mindbrix/TSAlertView).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with this type of controller (`UITableView` in `UIAlertView`) and wested so much time to debug this issue.

This is disappointing that from `iOS7` you can not add any `subview` to `UIAlertView`, and all this type of controller uses the same method. They inserts `UITableView` as `subview` of `UIAlertView`.

So for your solution you have to drop option for using this controller and create your own controller or find some other controller as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 onwards you cant addSubView.. So if you can determine the OS version and set the table accordingly.

```
#define IS_OS_7_OR_LATER  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)

if(IS_OS_7_OR_LATER) {

    [yourAlertView setValue:yourTableView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
}
else
{  
   [yourAlertView addSubview:yourTableView];
}
```

Instead of using a custom library, create your own tableViewcontroller class and add it as a sub view or set it for accessory view.